# spring mvc how to get build success or failure state, after build has finished and created .war file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc, spring-data

I just want to execute a local "cmd" file right after finished and success to build .war file.

on spring boot Web Application i have tested successfully on this code.

```
//MainApplication.java
@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
public void doSomethingAfterStartup() {
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
    processBuilder.command("cmd.exe", "/c", "ls D:\\workspace\\web\\target\\");
    processBuilder.command("D:\\workspace\\web\\target\\example.cmd");

    try {
        Process process = processBuilder.start();
        BufferedReader reader =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        int exitCode = process.waitFor();
        System.out.println("\nExited with error code : " + exitCode);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But how to get mvc build state, in order to execute a .cmd file right after build has finished and created .war file on /target directory successfully.

this code doesn't run on mvc build.

Thank you!

Comment: What should the cmd file do for your spring boot application? Furthermore based on the given code your cmd file will be started after your Spring Boot application has been startet which is not related to the build ?

Comment: @khmarbaise it is aws s3 cli upload automation file. it doesnt have any impacts on spring boot application. it is just need to execute when spring mvc build finished

Comment: The `ApplicationReadyEvent` is fired by the Spring Boot Application itself and has nothing to do with build...

Comment: and why should it? Building is only createing the war/jar file. It isn't going to execute your code.

Comment: @M.Deinum i understand but thats why i ask a question about mvc build state. for the deploy automation on aws cli to run applications. my boss ask me to automate this.